# JavaScript setting pointer-events

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set `pointer-events: none` for a div through JavaScript, however the property is not being applied.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("div").setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
```

And:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.pointer-events = "none";
```

But neither worked, **any ideas?**

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Your first attempt failed because it was a CSS property and not an attribute (part of the `style` attribute).

Your second attempt failed because for some off reason, when making this API `casing-like-this` gets converted to `camelCasingLikeThis` . This is *likely* because the folks who built JavaScript and the folks who built CSS weren't very well coordinated.

The following should work:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Comment: Glad I could help, also, you might find this interesting: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs

Comment: Can you please link to the documentation where these JavaScript style attributes are listed? I can't see anything about `pointerEvents` mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), for example.

Comment: @Mitch sure, in general, MDN is not a speficification reference (it's a user friendly manual). It is [defined here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ElementCSSInlineStyle) and more recently [in the new spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-style-attribute) to map to [the style attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/). Pointer events [are specced here](https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/) and the property itself `pointer-events` originates in [svg](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum wait... where is the user friendly reference amongst those links? :p

Comment: @Mitch the actual "spec" [is here](https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#pointer-events) and here is the relevant MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sorry, but I still don't see any mention of the JavaScript `pointerEvents` property in any of those links.

Comment: @Mitch it's implicit, it's not a JavaScript property - as the documents I linked to say - CSS properties `go-like-this` and JS properties `goLikeThis`, via the `style` property you can access _any_ CSS property, but you need to apply the conversion - in the case of pointer events it's from `pointer-events` to `pointEvents` as specified in the algorithm that converts between IDL (The DOM language) and CSS here: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#css-property-to-idl-attribute

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks. :) I just needed to know that there was a method to the madness, and not that it was just some arbitrary choice of variable names without documentation.

Comment: "This is likely because the guys who built JavaScript and the guys who built CSS weren't very well coordinated." JavaScript is case sensitive, CSS is not. CSS doesn't recognize whitespace intervals, therefore it needs - so thay don't collapse in one token, otherwise it needs ;, but JS does, and when it'll break the token therefore the capitalized letter in the middle of some letters means it carries a whitespace. Which means that  they are two separate languages and have different parsers and different syntax. They couldn't 'coordinate' even if theye wanted to.

Comment: Sure they could - they could either make `-` a valid character JS identifier or make CSS case sensitive and use camel case or make properties quoted in CSS or do a variety of other things. Just because they can't coordinate at this point doesn't mean they couldn't when the properties were written.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum @Bekim Bacay - the reason for this is not "a poorly coordinated issue".  Its because in JS the `-` is the math minus sign. `var el=document.getElementById(this); el.pointer-events = 'none' `will produce an error "Invalid left hand assignment.  JS is treating it as `el.pointer - events`, and thus needing a left hand var assignment ie: `var newEl = el.pointer - events = "none" ;` (this still wouldn't work, but JS wouldn't complain about left hand assignments.  This is why CSS manipulation in JS removes the `-`I think for consistency sake they should have used `_` instead

Answer (score 14):

You can access style properties via [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like this:

```
document.getElementById("div").style['pointer-events'] = 'auto';
```

No need in camel case modification in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](http://granite.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/B/bbox2.3.svg) in a [book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/building-web-applications/9780735675742/) which uses `element.setAttributeNS(null, "pointer-events", "none");` instead of using `element.style.pointer-events = "none";`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but I think I have figured it out...

In the first code, it would be,

```
document.getElementById("div").setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none;");
```

Here you can see, I have added the HTML attribute "style" as the first argument and then passed the the CSS property along with its value in the second argument.

And in the second code, it would be,

```
document.getElementById("div").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Here you just have to use camelCase instead of kebab-case.

Both of the ways are correct and both of them works...