# How do I activate a disabled link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create link that will activate when a specified value is created. If I have a link like:

```
a(class="nav-link" id="signal_" style="pointer-events: none" href="/goToStreamingPage") <i class="fas fa-signal"></i> #{signal}
input(hidden id="signalInput" value=signal)
```

how would I go about changing the style pointer-events from none to auto?

I've tried:

```
$(function() {
    let signals = document.getElementById('signalInput')
    console.log(signals.value)
    if(signals.value === "Live"){
      signals.style.pointer-events = "auto";
      console.log("goofy")
    }
})
```

but this throws an error with the output saying there is an Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Check this:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492421/7812329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access style properties via [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like this:

```
signals.style['pointer-events'] = 'auto'
```

No need in camel case modification in this case.

Answer (score 1):

User camel case for modifying css in javascript

```
signals.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
```

Comment: That's it, I didn't know pointer events can be written that way

Comment: When dealing with css property with hyphen in it, you always have to change it to camel case ;)