# Removing one style from div insead of whole style with click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a canvas div like this

```
`<div id="canvas" style="pointer-events:none;">`
```

I have a button that when pressed removes the style

```
`<input id="" onclick="qqq()" class="button_text" type="button" name="test" value="test"/>`
```

```
    function qqq() {
    document.getElementById("canvas").removeAttribute("style");
    alert("I was ran");
    
      }
```

Is there a eazy way to make it to change the pointer event from none to null instead of removing the style??? I cant find another way to do it. I tried using disabled=disabled and yes im aware to change onclick to event listener.

Comment: You can manipulate the `style` object directly. It's a property of the element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration

Comment: @RenevanderLende that is not what this question is about. The OP wants to change a property on the `style` object, not on the element itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript setting pointer-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492401/javascript-setting-pointer-events)

Answer (score 1):

Access the `style` property of the element once you find it, and then alter it to your liking:

```
function qqq() {
    document.getElementById("canvas").style.pointerEvents = null;
    alert("I was ran");
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to simply [remove or toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (depending on your specific case) a custom utility class like `no-pointer`:

```js
const togglePointerEvents = () => {
  document.querySelector("#canvas").classList.toggle("no-pointer");
};

document.querySelector("#togglePointerEvents").addEventListener("click", togglePointerEvents);
```

```css
.no-pointer {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas" class="no-pointer">Some DIV element</div>
<button id="togglePointerEvents">Toggle pointer events</button>
```

Or, instead of `toggle` use `classList.remove("no-pointer")`, you get the idea.
Also, don't use HTML inline `on*` handlers. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. JS is supposed to be in one place and that's the respective tag or file. Not disseminated in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to leave inline styles in the tag unless they are needed, as they have the highest priority. It is a good practice to use css classes with the necessary styles instead.
Therefore, there are two options:

- add/remove a class (recommended)
- remove the style attribute or change its content (not recommended)

```js
const toggleNoEvents = () => {
  const canvasId = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  canvasId.classList.toggle('no_events');
};
```

```css
.no_events {
  pointer-events:none;
  /* to test */
  user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas" class="no_events">test</div>

<button onclick='toggleNoEvents()'>Toggle no events</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

when a user checks the box they can use the canvas then they don't check the box they cannot use the canvas this is what worked for me kinda a buggy I had to use '' on one and not the other to get it too work. and even then its pointerEvents and not pointer-events..

on

```
function signatureClear() {
document.getElementById("canvasWrap").style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}
```

off

```
function qqq() {
document.getElementById("canvasWrap").style.pointerEvents = null;
}
```