# JavaScript setting pointer-events from none to auto

Tags: javascript, pointer-events

I need a way to overwrite my elements that are set to pointer-events:none. I have already tried a few things, but it doesn't seem to be able to control the elements under this setting.

```
const meinElement = document.getElementById('hovertest');

      meinElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
          meinElement.style.pointerEvents = "none"; 
          meinElement.classList.add('hovered'); 
      });

      meinElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
          meinElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";
          meinElement.classList.remove('hovered'); 
      });
```

```
  #hovertest {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
  }

  .hovered {
      background-color: red; 
      pointer-events: auto;
  }
```

I have already tried this suggestion, which didn’t work.
[JavaScript setting pointer-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492401/javascript-setting-pointer-events)

I expected the JS to override the setting, but that is not the case.

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem, indicating specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Comment: This is not working because once your mouseenter event work post this nothing will work because of pointer event none so you can achieve same using CSS  pointer-events: none;

Comment: Please explain in detail what is your expectation and how - precisely! - your code fails that expectation.

Comment: David's comment should be the recommended edit for this question. A testable script would be ideal in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the `meinElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";` because when you add this it will `hover` only one time and add.
It happens because when you set it to "none"; it can't be changed anymore. [Add CSS cursor property when using "pointer-events: none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654413/add-css-cursor-property-when-using-pointer-events-none)

```js
const meinElement = document.getElementById('hovertest');

meinElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    
   meinElement.classList.add('hovered');
});

meinElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {

    meinElement.classList.remove('hovered');
});
```

```css
#hovertest {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}

.hovered {
    background-color: red ;
    pointer-events: auto ;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="hovertest">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```